# How to access control of another class in mainwindow WPF using vb

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox

I'm trying to call text box in another class from the MainWindow in WPf using this code:

```
 Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

 Mainwindowtext2.Text = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, Window1).text1.Text

 End Sub
```

When I compile there are no errors, but after a Button Click this error comes out

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled
"Unable to cast object of type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' to type 'WpfApplication1.Window1'."
```

Is there another way to get the control from another class while in MainWindow?

Comment: WPF is a complex framework in and of itself. I suggest you get familiar with .Net and OOP concepts before diving into it. Maybe try some console applications, or search for an intro tutorial about OOP and programming in general.

Comment: Well the error is telling you your cast is incorrect (Application.Current.MainWindow) is not of type Window1.  Hard to tell much else given what you've shown us.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia <br/> I'm trying to control the text box from another class in MainWindow. In Windows Form it should look like this <br/> `me.Mainwindowtext2.text = form2.text1.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error code you're getting:

Unable to cast object of type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' to type 'WpfApplication1.Window1'.

The object you have is of type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow'. This means that you can't cast it to 'WpfApplication1.Window1'.

Because your root namespace is 'WpfApplication1', the code should read:

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Mainwindowtext2.Text = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow).text1.Text
End Sub
```

To understand why, the static property `Application.Current` is holding a reference to the class `Application`. It's `MainWindow` property is of type `Window`. In your application, your main window is type `MainWindow`, which derives from `Window`, and can therefore be returned from the `Application.Current.MainWindow` property. That is why you need to cast it to `MainWindow`.

**EDIT**

If you are trying to get an instance of a different window than the main window, you can use the application's Windows property:

```
Mainwindowtext2.Text = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of Window1)().First().text1.Text
```

The way WPF creates the backing fields, this should work as long as the classes are in the same assembly. If they aren't, consider creating a read-only property to expose the text, or set the [FieldModifier property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) in XAML.

Comment: But if I cast it to MainWindow I cannot get the controls in another class. If I change `Window1` to `MainWindow` i will get the controls in the MainWindow. I'm trying to get the textbox in another class. Is the code wrong?

Comment: @ReignKeith if you know the class and have an instance of it add a public property to it in order to expose the information that you are wanting from the textbox.

Comment: @MarkHall  I tried this but still can't call textbox.  `Public Class Window1
    Private Textbox2 As TextBox<br/>
    Public ReadOnly Property text1() As TextBox<br/>
        Get<br/>
            Return Textbox2<br/>
        End Get<br/>
    End Property`<br/> 
`Class MainWindow<br/>
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)<br/>
        MainWindowText2.Text = Window1.textbox2.text<br/>
    End Sub` <br/>There is an error "WpfApplication1.Window1.Textbox2 is not accessible in this context because it is Private"

Comment: @ReignKeith You are still trying to access the TextBox directly, not your Property. Also it looks like you are trying to get the value from your Window1 Class not an instance of your Class. You need to be using something like this. `MainWindowText2.Text = "Your Window1 Instance Name".text1.Text` replace the "Your Window1 Instance name with the variable that you created when you newed up your instance of Window1

Comment: @MarkHall, I've updated the answer to show how to get an instance of another window in your application that isn't the MainWindow.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht Sorry I felt that I hijacked your answer. but hopefully that will help the OP

Comment: @MarkHall no worries, hopefully we can help him learn these fundamental concepts! And also, like an idiot I replied to you instead of the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, The code worked great! I Still have a lot to learn. Thanks again for helping and explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please change your code:

Mainwindowtext2.Text = DirectCast(Application.Current.Window1, Window1).text1.Text
```

Hope This helps you...

try this...
You can use the Binding concept as below:

**in .CS File:**

```
Private _TextBoxName As String

Public Property TextBoxName() As String
    Get
        Return _TextBoxName
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        _TextBoxName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**in Xaml:**

```
< TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxName}"/>
```

Now you can use the value of Textbox as Follows:

```
Window1textbox.Text = mainwindow.TextBoxName
```

Comment: Tried it but there is an error message "'Window1' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Application'"